Tensorflow binary crossentropy always predicts the same value
I'm new to the general stack overflow community and especially new to the Tensorflow library (1 week as of now). So I'm positive I am missing something here, just can't quite figure it out myself.
I have done a few practices utilizing Tensorflow's example dataset and a few miscellaneous tutorials. I found myself attempting to apply one of the tutorial's code to my own dataset, this dataset is a csv and the model should return it's prediction of the "Last Result" column. This turned out to be a bit much because I quickly encountered a problem, the "predict" function always predicts identical values for every data entry.
[[0.6335701]
[0.6335701]
...
[0.6335701]
[0.6335701]]
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from keras.models import Sequential, load_model
from keras.layers import Dense
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

df = pd.read_csv('*.csv')
x = pd.get_dummies(df.drop(['Last Result'], axis=1))
y = df['Last Result'].apply(lambda X: 1 if X == 'Registered' else 0)
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=.2)
x_train.head()
print("x train: \n", x_train)
y_train.head()
print("y train: \n", y_train)

# Below is code to create a new TensorFlow Model. If you need to call a saved model, see 'load model' below.

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(units=32, activation='relu', input_dim=len(x_train.columns)))
model.add(Dense(units=32, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(units=1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='sgd', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=100, batch_size=128)

# model.save('*.keras')

# This is code to recall a previously saved TensorFlow Model

# model = load_model('*.keras')

y_hat = model.predict(x_test)
# y_hat = [0 if val < 0.5 else 1 for val in y_hat]
print(y_hat)

# print(accuracy_score(y_test, y_hat))

I have tried other suggestions from similar posts to no avail. My best understanding of the issue is that the model is not learning anything and is instead just guessing all one value because one of the expected values is true ~60% of the time, thus the ~.60 predictions.
Any help on the matter would mean a great deal in assisting my understanding of the library. Thanks in advance and thank you for your time.

You need to remove the pd.get_dummies function call. Just directly assign
x = df.drop(['Last Result'], axis=1)

Calling pd.get_dummies converts the samples into 0/1 data: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html.
Can you give more information about the nature of your dataset? This would help in understanding what you are trying to do.

Apologies for the delayed response, and thank you, @Bongni for a clear and concise answer. However, when removing the .getdummies function, I now get an error on line 31 'model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=100, batch_size=128)' stating "ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'SK'". For context, the database is an old call file containing information about particular contacts in a database. This data includes Region, Email/SMS Permissions, Geography and a few other strings. Needless to say the data is not optimized for the task whatsoever, this is just a proof of concept.

Alright I see the problem. You can try to convert the strings into numbers. For example if you have ten regions, label them from 0 to 9. Then you can repeat this for all entries. This should give more meaningful data than applying .get_dummies.

Quick counter question, would the model then treat the 0 to 9 as literal values or 'buckets'? And if so is there a way to predetermine how it treats these? Also, I've just recently discovered the world of preprocessing so this is beginning to make much more sense. Thank you for your help.

It should treat them as literal values. What exactly do you mean by predetermining how it treats them?
